# missing() behaviour in R

Tags: r, function

I'm writing the **R function below** in which `missing()` is giving me problems. As commented in the code, the first `ifelse` works great, but not the second. Why?

```r
powert <- function(d, a, n1, n2, tl) {
  H1 <- seq(-3, 3, by = .001)
  df <- ifelse(missing(n2), n1-1, (n1+n2)-2)        # Behaving fine
  Hcp <- ifelse(missing(n2), H1*sqrt(n1), H1*sqrt((n1*n2)/(n1+n2))) # !!! MISBEHAVING !!! #

  tcrit2 <- ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 > 0, qt(1-a, df), 
              ifelse(tl == 2 & H1 > 0, -qt(a/2,df), 
                ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 < 0, qt(a,df),
                  ifelse(tl == 2 & H1 < 0, qt(a/2,df), 
                    ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 == 0, qt(1-a,df), -qt(a/2,df))
            ))))

  TII <- ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 > 0, pt(tcrit2, df, Hcp), 
           ifelse(tl == 2 & H1 > 0, pt(tcrit2, df, Hcp) - pt(-tcrit2, df, Hcp),
             ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 < 0, 1-pt(tcrit2, df, Hcp), 
               ifelse(tl == 2 & H1 < 0, 1-(pt(tcrit2, df, Hcp) + (1-pt(-tcrit2, df, Hcp))),
                 ifelse(tl == 1 & H1 == 0, 1-a, 1-a)
         ))))

  Pwr <- 1-TII

  ESto80 <- if (d>0) { 
              H1[min(which(Pwr >= .8 & H1 > 0))]
            } else 
            if (d<0) { 
              H1[max(which(Pwr >= .8 & H1 < 0))]
            }

            else {0}
  
  plot(H1, Pwr, type = "l", las = 1, yaxs = "i", ylim = c(0,1), lwd = 2)
  cat("DF behaving fine = ", df)
}

## Verify here:
powert(d = .5, a = .05, n1 = 20, n2 = 20, tl = 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Hcp <- ifelse( missing(n2), H1 * sqrt(n1), H1 * sqrt((n1*n2)/(n1+n2)) )
```

use

```
if (missing(n2)) Hcp <- H1 * sqrt(n1)
else Hcp <- H1 * sqrt((n1*n2)/(n1+n2))
```

The length of the object that `ifelse` returns is determined by the length of the logical statement. Here, `H1` is a vector created by `seq`, but `missing(n2)` is a single logical value. So, if you use `ifelse`, you only get one value out of it, rather than a vector value. This tells you that `ifelse` can not be used equivalently to `if ... else ...`.